# Numpy in1D multiple evaluation statements

Tags: python, numpy, evaluation

I'm trying to use numpy as opposed to nested for loops and trying to find if a value is within a particular tolerance.

The code in python using the nested loops works fine and I do get the results I'm looking for but unfortunately is not scalable and takes a couple of hours when the size of the list is 200k plus items.

What I have now as a second iteration of the process is:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from numpy import newaxis

#some data provided as an example
a= np.array([['id1', 8988, 7997, 210.0, 240.0, 180, 300, 7000.0, 9038, 8938, 8047, 7947, 231.0, 189.0, 8400.0, 5600.0],
['id2', 7314, 5613, 210.0, 240.0, 180, 300, 7000.0, 7364, 7264, 5663, 5563, 231.0, 189.0, 8400.0, 5600.0],
['id3', 5520, 9888, 35.0, 55.0, -125, 235, 7000.0, 5570, 5470, 9938, 9838, 38.5, 31.5, 8400.0, 5600.0],
['id4', 6270, 4270, 0.0, 90.0, -90, 270, 7000.0, 6320, 6220, 4320, 4220, 0.0, 0.0, 8400.0, 5600.0]])

print(a)

validation = np.ma.MaskedArray(((a[:, 1:2] <= a[:, 8:9]) & (a[:, 1:2] >= a[:, 9:10])) \
    & ((a[:, 2:3] <= a[:, 10:11]) & (a[:, 2:3] >= a[:, 11:12])) \
    & ((a[:, 3:4] <= a[:, 12:13]) & (a[:, 3:4] >= a[:, 13:14])) \
    & ((a[:, 7:8] <= a[:, 14:15]) & (a[:, 7:8] >= a[:, 15:])))

e = np.in1d(a[:, 1:2], a[validation]) <-- this is were I try to apply the check for tolerances
e1 = np.where(e[:, newaxis], a[:, :1], np.zeros(1, dtype=int))
ef = e1[~np.all(e1 == 0, axis=0)]

print('Final array', ef)
```

On the first attempt using numpy's meshgrid to create all combinations, one for each comparison, and then doing a numpy.where on the results it works but when using 100k plus items, the total amount of RAM required is more than 150GB of RAM.

Any help, advice, comment is appreciated.

Comment: Why use `masked array`?  Start with that logical expression.  That should be an array of shape `(n,1)` and dtype boolean.  Another thing, skip the attempt to work with a 2d array.  `np.in1d` words in `1d`.

Answer (score 0):

If I copy-n-paste your `a` I get a 4x16 array of strings

```
In [37]: a
Out[37]: 
array([['id1', '8988', '7997', '210.0', '240.0', '180', '300', '7000.0',
        '9038', '8938', '8047', '7947', '231.0', '189.0', '8400.0',
        '5600.0'],
      ....
      dtype='<U6')
```

Applying your `validation` expression to that produces (forget about the Maskedarray bit).  Of course it is trying to do a comparison of strings.

```
array([[ True],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [ True]], dtype=bool)
```

If I remove the `id` column I get a 4x15 of floats

```
In [39]: a
Out[39]: 
array([[ 8988. ,  7997. ,   210. ,   240. ,   180. ,   300. ,  7000. ,
         9038. ,  8938. ,  8047. ,  7947. ,   231. ,   189. ,  8400. ,
         5600. ],
...]])
```

WIth that I think the `validation` test can be simplified to:

```
In [41]: ((a[:, 0] <= a[:, 7]) & (a[:, 0] >= a[:, 8])) \
    ...:     & ((a[:, 1] <= a[:, 9]) & (a[:, 1] >= a[:, 10])) \
    ...:     & ((a[:, 2] <= a[:, 11]) & (a[:, 2] >= a[:, 12])) \
    ...:     & ((a[:, 6] <= a[:, 13]) & (a[:, 6] >= a[:, 14]))
Out[41]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

What is this doing?

```
e = np.in1d(a[:, 1:2], a[validation])
```

`a[validation]` is all the `ok` rows of `a`; `a[:,0]` is the first value of each row.  But `np.in1d` is meant to check the contents of one 1d array against the contents of another 1d.  As you wrote it, it is using 2 2d arrays.

At this point, I'm going to give up.

Construct a simpler test case, and make sure it works at each step.  Show the intermediate values.  Then we can discuss the step(s) where it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As hpaulj says, first get rid of the `id`'s.

Second, why are your tolerances and your values in the same array? If you had `min_tol` and `max_tol` in separate arrays, you could do this much more easily.

You probably need something like (after removing the `id`'s):

```
min_tol = a[:, 8:15:2]
max_tol = a[:, 7:14:2]
a_val = np.c_[a[:, :3], a[:, 6]]
validation = (a_val >= min_tol) & (a_val <= max_tol)
```

Although I'm really not sure at this stage...